# Inflated view not updating

Tags: android, android-layout

I inflated layout `activity_main`, but when I click on a button nothing happens, textview is not updated.
Here is the code:

```
private int clicks = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    View myview = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    wm.addView(myview, params);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clicks +=1;

            textview.setText("Clicks: " + clicks);
        }
    });
}
```

It looks like click on a button updates textview in first `activity_main` (`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`), and not the one in inflated view (the one that is in front).

Why is that happening, and how to make that click on a button updates textview in inflated view?

Also, is there a way to only have inflated view? If I remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` app crashes.

Comment: why do you want to inflate activity_main again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `textview` is contained within the inflated view, you need to specify that you're searching that view when you call `findViewById()`:

`TextView textview = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.textview);`

You'll have to do the same with the button.

If you want to have it be the only view, you'll have to call `setContentView` at the end. It was likely crashing because of your use of `findViewById()`, which I believe was inherently searching the current view (which is null before setting the content view).

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the LayoutInflater, setContentView() does that for you.

```
private int clicks = 0;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             clicks +=1;

             textview.setText("Clicks: " + clicks);
        }
    });
```

}

That's all you need.